# MySQL Query: How to sum 3 different values in a column, showing total of each value in result set

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have a table called inventory that includes two columns as follows:

[image]

I would like to query this table to return a result set that lists how many items of each condition I have (column headers show in example below are not wanted in result set...just show here to give clarity):

[image]

I guess it would look something like:

```
  SELECT item, sum(condition???), sum(condition???), sum(condition???) 
    FROM inventory 
GROUP BY item
```

How can I accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: You're almost there - here's the [MySQL documentation for Control of Flow syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were very close:

```
SELECT item, 
  sum(case when `condition` = 'poor' then 1 else 0 end) as poor, 
  sum(case when `condition` = 'fair' then 1 else 0 end) as fair, 
  sum(case when `condition` = 'good' then 1 else 0 end) as good
FROM inventory 
GROUP BY item
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc6d5/4)

Comment: Thank you bluefeet! This is perfect! I appreciate the time to point me in the right direction.

Comment: @user1218172 you are welcome, you were very close to the solution on your own, you just needed a little help.